# node.js mongoose multiple database across project using same schema

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I want to make use of multiple databases in a project, but I am having difficulty in calling the 
secondary databases across many route controllers. I do not want to close connection to the main databases

the current method which I have used to insert data into multiple controllers I believe is not efficient 
enough i.e.

```
------>>        all these are called every time a file needs to connect to the secondary database
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
var mongoose = require('mongoose');                                                     |
var mongooseConnect = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/27017/'+dbName);   |
                                                                                        |
require('./models');                                                                    |
var modelData = mongooseConnect.model('models');                                        |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
modelData.save()
```

I am looking for a method which would allow me to

1. connect to the secondary database once and call it anytime i want to across the controllers
2. combine the above code into a one line code

I have called the main database through the normal means which is

route.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
mongoose.connect(mongodbhost/maindb)
```

then in the schema I just simply require mongoose before using it in the schema. and only the schema is called in the
route controllers.
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same schema in multiple database but you would need to create the connections to both databases. Here's how you can do it:

```
const conn1 = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/test1');
const conn2 = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/test2');

const TestSchema = require('./TestSchema');
var TestModelDb1 = conn1.model('Model', TestSchema);
var TestModelDb2 = conn2.model('Model', TestSchema);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but what I want to do is to declare the secondary connection
once and make it available across all other route controller. The method you just wrote is similar to what I have written
above

Comment: Just call the appropriate model in the controllers. The connection is only created once.

Comment: Please I do not get you. I believe when I change from one route to the other route It would be calling the maindb and not the secondary db which I want to make use of